# Allowing user to only create certain amount of objects with non-paid account, using Django Stripe (dj-stripe)

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I currently have a Personal CRM app that allow user to create Contacts and then create Logs for those contacts. Here is how the code looks like.

**views.py**

```py
class CreateContact(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Contact
    template_name = 'network/contacts_list.html'
    form_class = ContactForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.contact_owner = self.request.user
        return super(CreateContact, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateContact, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['contacts'] = Contact.objects.filter(contact_owner=self.request.user)
        return context



class CreateContactLog(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = ContactLog
    template_name = 'network/contact_detail.html'
    fields = ('log_type','body',)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('contact-detail', kwargs={'id':self.kwargs['id']})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        current_contact = Contact.objects.get(contact_owner=self.request.user, contact_id=self.kwargs['id'])
        form.instance.contact_owner = self.request.user
        form.instance.contact_id = current_contact
        return super(CreateContactLog, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        current_contact = Contact.objects.get(contact_owner=self.request.user, contact_id=self.kwargs['id'])
        context = super(CreateContactLog, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["contact_info"] = current_contact
        context["first_name"] = current_contact.first_name
        context["id"] = current_contact.contact_id
        context['log_entries'] = ContactLog.objects.filter(contact_owner=self.request.user, contact_id=current_contact)
        return context
```

Everything is working perfectly.

Now I want to start accepting payments I want to integrate my app with Stripe. The best way to do this is with the third party package [dj-stripe](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe).

I want to have 2 plans, free and paid. I want to allow free plan users to create up to 10 contacts. Reading the documentations for django-stripe I see that I can use class based views, but I dont't understand how I would approach limiting certain number of object creations.

Here are my current thoughts:

- Perhaps creating two classes, one of which will allow to create three objects and another class will allow unlimited but will require payments.
- Perhaps there is a setting in the [documentation](https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) I have missed that will be able to help with this.

**What is the best way to approach this problem?**

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thank you very much in advance.

Best,
Rasul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a util function that checks:

1. how many contacts a user has
2. whether or not a user has a paid plan

Check 1 is a straightforward count on the reverse relation on `contact_owner`.

dj-stripe has [`Customer.get_or_create()`](https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/models.html#djstripe.models.Customer.get_or_create) and [`Customer.has_active_subscription()`](https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/models.html#djstripe.models.Customer.has_active_subscription) methods you can use in check 2.

You can then check the result of this util in your `form_valid`. If the result is false, you can [add an error to the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error) and then call `form_invalid`.

Hope that helps,

Alex